# Does the same origin forbid third party scripts loaded in by a domain, from sending requests to that domain?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I know the same origin policy prevents javascript on other sites from sending requests to my domain, but does the same origin policy also protect me from third party scripts loaded in by my domain, from sending requests to my domain? E.g can a third pary script from evil.com loaded in by a website on example.com send requests to example.com?

Comment: yes it can send requests Same origin policy is to keep the browser from reading content from the other domain, not preventing it from sending data there.

Comment: But what if that request is a get request? then that script would get some data back right? And the question is not about sending requests to evil.com, it is about sending requests to example.com, there's no "other domain" here except the source of the third party script.

Comment: We make get requests all the time for images, scripts, stylesheets to other domains.

Comment: yes but this question isn't about requests to other domains, it's about requests to the current domain.

Comment: Well if the script is running in your page it can do what it wants.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer i was looking for :)

Comment: Do you know if this also applies to scripts in iframes? I know they can't access the main sites cookies, but can they send (cookieless) requests to the main sites webserver?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox